# LINQ, Joins, Grouping and Aggregates

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using either a Join or GroupJoin, is there any way to produce aggregates values for fields in both the parent and child tables. Given an Orders table and an OrderDetails table, Using the 2 steps below I can obtain an aggregate (MAX) from the Orders and an aggregate (SUM) from the OrderDetails.

STEP 1:

```
var query = from o in orders
                    join d in details on o.OrderId equals d.OrderId
                    select new
                    {
                        order = o.OrderId,
                        maximum = o.UserId,
                        quantity = d.Quantity
                    };
```

Step 2:

```
var result = (from q in query
                      group q by q.order into g
                      select new 
                      {
                          OrderId = g.Key,
                          MaxUnits = g.Max(q => q.maximum),
                          Available = (g.Max(q => q.maximum) - g.Sum(q => q.quantity))
                      });
```

However, when I try to combine these as in:

```
var finalresult   = orders  
                    .GroupJoin(  details,  
                    o => o.OrderId,  
                    d => d.OrderDetailId,  
                    (o, grp) => new {
                        OrderId = o.OrderId,
                        MaxUnits = grp.Max(o => o.maximum),
                        Available = (grp.Max(o => o.maximum) - grp.Sum(d => d.Quantity))
                    });
```

.. the value 'o' is out of scope inside the grouped set 'grp'. So grp.Max(o => o.maximum) results in an error. It appears that only aggregate values for the child table (OrderDetail) are available.

So does anyone know if it is possible to obtain aggregates from both the Child and Parent tables in a single query?

Comment: Can't you combine them using the let keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` *is* a single query.  The beauty of LINQ and deferred execution is that no actual computation has happened in Step 1, only a query has been defined.  Step 2 then builds ontop of that query to create another *single* query.  When you execute `result` that query will be executed as a single block.

I recommend splitting up larger queries into smaller easier to understand pieces like in the first two examples.  Using good names for the queries can make them much easier to read.  For example, I might name query orderQuantities.  `from q in query` does not convey much meaning, but `from oq in orderQuantities` lets me know what kind of data the query is over.

If you really think you need them together:

```
var query = orders.Join(details, o => o.OrderId, d => d.OrderId, 
    (o, d) => new {
        order = o.OrderId, 
        maximum = o.UserId, 
        quantity = d.Quantity
    }).GroupBy(oq => oq.order)
    .Select(g => new {
        OrderId = g.Key, 
        MaxUnits = g.Max(q => q.maximum), 
        Available = (g.Max(q => q.maximum) - g.Sum(q => q.quantity))
    });
```

Now that is ugly...

Comment: They do say beauty is in the eye of the beholder and while I don't find your response that ugly, I will follow your advice to keep things separate for the reasons you state. Being an old SQL guy I tend to forget about deferred execution and try to consolidate wherever possible. I believe that the real value of your answer lies in that fact alone. There is a high probability that LINQ can consolidate and optimize far better than I could anyway. Thanks for your time.